# Why my SiftingAppender stop working when I used a RollingFileAppender?

Tags: java, logging, logback

In my logback config file, I have the following appender that work :

```
<appender name="thread_SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="[...]"/>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${threadName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>[...]/${bySecond}/${threadName}.log</file>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
               <pattern>%date %level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

The file are created correctly.  If I replace FileAppender by RollingFileAppender, nothing is created.  Why?  How can I make it work>

The threadName is set by the discriminator.

Comment: Have you specified the requested parameters of this kind of appender (rolling policy, etc.)? See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: @Benoit, I also have a version with a complex rolling policy, but that won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in package name.  It seem error under the tag sift are silently ignore.  To test, I need to copy the appender outside the sift tag, make sure I have no error and copy it back.

Answer (score 5):

The [OnConsoleStatusListener](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#statusListener) is your friend. Just add

```
<configuration>
  <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />
  .. remainder of your config file
</configuration>
```

at the beginning of your configuration file to see the errors generated by `SiftingAppender`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the property `${bySecond}` or any one else is lost inside `sift > appender` tag.

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@23:97 - no applicable
action for [property], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][property]]
[...]/bySecond_IS_UNDEFINED/main.log
```

Answer (score -1):

In complement to my comment, you can verify that a file is correctly created using this appender in your sift appender (taken from the Logback Tutorial about RollingFileAppender configuration).

```
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>test.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>tests.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```